# android web view links are opening in browser. need to open in app

Tags: android, web-applications

I followed a tutorial from youtube but I got an error, the links are not opening in an app but are opening in the browser, I am using android studio 2.3.3 and navigational template. How do I correct? In my studio, the shouldoverloadurl is stricken and when I use the app the links are opening in browser but not in app itself

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.devmetsu.com")) {
        //open url contents in webview
        return false;
    } else {
        //here open external links in external browser or app
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: try `url.contains("www.devmetsu.com")`

Comment: does the url contain a specific Url ?

Comment: it does contain a specific url

Answer (score 0):

// Try this method,

```
 private void startWebView(String url) {

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog == null) {
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }
        });
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webview.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Comment: if you are using WebViewClient then open webpage in app. above method is also working and open webpage in app not browser.